# Installing eyeD3 on Webfaction

Tags: django, easy-install, id3

I'm trying to install eyeD3 on Webfaction for my Django application and I tried to this command

```
easy_install-2.7 eyeD3
```

and it didn't work, also Webfaction prevents me from downloading packages as well right? 
I could install "boto" with the very same command tho. 
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

You can always pull down whatever packages you need and place them into your /lib/python2.x folder within your application directory. WebFaction doesn't prevent you from downloading or installing packages using pip or easy_install.

Have a look at their documentation: http://docs.webfaction.com/software/python.html?highlight=install%20python%20pacakge#installing-python-packages

If that doesn't help, just contact technical support, their staff is extremely helpful.

Comment: Here is what happens when I run `easy_install-2.7 eyeD3` 

Searching for eyeD3
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/eyeD3/
Reading http://eyeD3.nicfit.net/
Reading http://eyed3.nicfit.net/
Best match: eyeD3 0.6.17
Downloading http://eyed3.nicfit.net/releases/eyeD3-0.6.17.tar.gz
Processing eyeD3-0.6.17.tar.gz
error: Couldn't find a setup script in /tmp/easy_install-nwJ5wc/eyeD3-0.6.17.tar.gz

Comment: In fact, I tried to install it with PIPE and i got an error, then i cd into my $HOME/build folder and i see the eyeD3 folder there but when i go to the python shell and try to import eyeD3 it doesn't recognize the module

Comment: What I do in circumstances like this is literally just ftp/scp the module from my workstation to WebFaction. Nothing says you have to install a module with pip or easy_install for it to work.

Comment: Excuse me, where exactly should I ftp the module? in the Python2.7 folder of my $HOME, or in my Python2.7's project? Also, does Filezilla work to FTP deploy the app/modules?

Comment: You need to ftp it to: $HOME/webapps/your_app/lib/python2.7, and yes, you can use FileZilla or even just a terminal/command line.

Comment: So I just need to upload my project folder on Webfaction and edit the settings.py accordingly and then i'm ready to go?

Comment: You should really get familiar with WebFaction's docs, as there are several steps to deploying your app

Answer (score 0):

eyeD3 is not packaged with a `setup.py` script, so its installation is a bit more complicated than simply easy_installing it.

Here are the commands you can run in a SSH session to install it in your home directory on your WebFaction server:

```
mkdir -p ~/tmp ~/src ~/lib/python2.7
export TMPDIR=~/tmp
cd ~/src
wget http://eyed3.nicfit.net/releases/eyeD3-0.6.17.tar.gz
tar zxf eyeD3-0.6.17.tar.gz
cd eyeD3-0.6.17
./configure --prefix=$HOME
cd ..
easy_install-2.7 eyeD3-0.6.17
```

Hope that helps!